# SQL - Selecting highest scores for different categories

Tags: sql

Lets say i've got a db with 3 tables:

- Players (PK id_player, name...),
- Tournaments (PK id_tournament, name...),
- Game (PK id_turn, FK id_tournament, FK id_player and score)

Players participate in tournaments. Table called Game keeps track of each player's score for different tournaments)

I want to create a view that looks like this:

```
    torunament_name     Winner     highest_score
    Tournament_1        Jones                300
    Tournament_2        White                250
```

I tried different aproaches but I'm fairly new to sql (and alsoto this forum)
I tried using union all clause like:

```
    select * from (select "Id_player", avg("score") as "Score" from 
    "Game" where "Id_tournament" = '1' group by "Id_player" order by 
    "Score" desc) where rownum <= 1 
    union all
    select * from (select "Id_player", avg("score") as "Score" from 
    "Game" where "Id_tournament" = '2' group by "Id_player" order by 
    "Score" desc) where rownum <= 1;
```

and ofc it works but whenever a tournament happens, i would have to manually add a select statement to this with Id_torunament = nextvalue

EDIT:
So lets say that player with id 1 scored 50 points in tournament a, player 2 scored 40 points, player 1 wins, so the table should show only player 1 as the winner (or if its possible 2or more players if its a tie) of this tournament. Next row shows the winner of second tournament. I dont think Im going to put multiple games for one player in the same tournament, but if i would, it would probably count avg from all his scores.

EDIT2:
Create table scripts:

```
    create table players 
    (id_player numeric(5) constraint pk_id_player primary key, name 
    varchar2(50));
    create table tournaments 
    (id_tournament numeric(5) constraint pk_id_tournament primary key, 
    name varchar2(50));
    create table game 
    (id_game numeric(5) constraint pk_game primary key, id_player 
    numeric(5) constraint fk_id_player references players(id_player), 
    id_tournament numeric(5) constraint fk_id_tournament references 
    tournaments(id_tournament), score numeric(3));
```

[RDBM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNogX.png)

FINAL EDIT:
Ok, in case anyone is wondering I used Jorge Campos script, changed it a bit and it works. Thank you all for helping. Unfortunately I cannot upvote comments yet, so I can only thank by posting. Heres the final script:

```
select
   t.name, 
   p.name as winner, 
   g.score
from
   game g inner join tournaments t
           on g.id_tournament = t.id_tournament
          inner join players p
           on g.id_player = p.id_player
          inner join 
              (select g.id_tournament, g.id_player,
                      row_number() over (partition by t.name order by 
    score desc) as rd from game g join tournaments t on 
    g.id_tournament = t.id_tournament
          ) a
       on g.id_player = a.id_player
          and g.id_tournament = a.id_tournament
          and a.rd=1
order by t.name, g.score desc;
```

Comment: What is your RDBMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query could be simplified depending on the RDBMs you are using.

```
select
   t.name, 
   p.name as winner, 
   g.score
from
   game g inner join tournaments t
           on g.id_tournament = t.id_tournament
          inner join players p
           on g.id_player = p.id_player
          inner join 
              (select id_tournament, 
                      id_player,
                      row_number() over (partition by t.name order by score desc) as rd
                 from game
              ) a
           on g.id_player = a.id_player
              and g.id_tournament = a.id_tournament
              and a.rd=1
order by t.name, g.score desc
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think I didnt put everything in my first post. So lets say that player with id 1 scored 50 points in tournament a, player 2 scored 40 points, player 1 wins, so the table should show only player 1 as the winner (or if its possible 2or more players if its a tie) of this tournament. Next row shows the winner of second tournament. I dont think Im going to put multiple games for one player in the same tournament, but if i would, it would probably count avg from all his scores. Can you help?

Comment: What is your database system? Mysql, sqlserver, oracle, postgresql?

Comment: Oracle. Im going to usethis in Application Express to show a simple report based on this select statement.

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Comment: "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" I'm checking if it works in Oracle SqlDeveloper
I edited my firstpost so i can give you more info

Comment: Hi Arthur, I just missed a comma after a field in a subquery. It should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want as "Display high score of each player in each tournament"
your query would be like below in MS Sql server

```
select 
        t.name as tournament_name,
        p.name as Winner,
        Max(g.score) as [Highest_Score]
from Tournmanents t
Inner join Game g on t.id_tournament=g.id_tournament
inner join Players p on p.id_player=g.id_player
group by 
g.id_tournament,
g.id_player,
t.name,
p.name
```

Comment: What if a tournament have more than one game? Your query doesn't cover this situation.

Comment: irrespective of the game, for each tournament my query pulls every players highest score. thats how question is framed.

Comment: You didn't understand me, if you have a t1 (as tournament 1) with two games as g1 and g2 and player A you query would fetch the player A twice for the same tournament. I know that the OP didn't explicit said anything about it, I just think that would be better to have only one tournament for each player as in his desired result. Not saying that your query is wrong. In that case you have to sum up all results for t1 not show all results of it.

Comment: I didnt group by game id. so my query pulls max(score) of the each player for each individual tournament the player played. I see what you are saying too.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this if this works for you

```
SELECT  tournemntData.id_tournament ,
        tournemntData.name ,
        dbo.Players.name ,
        tournemntData.Score
FROM    dbo.Game
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT dbo.Tournaments.id_tournament ,
                            dbo.Tournaments.name ,
                            MAX(dbo.Game.score) AS Score
                     FROM   dbo.Game
                            INNER JOIN dbo.Tournaments ONTournaments.id_tournament = Game.id_tournament
                            INNER JOIN dbo.Players ON Players.id_player = Game.id_player
                     GROUP BY dbo.Tournaments.id_tournament ,
                            dbo.Tournaments.name
                   ) tournemntData ON tournemntData.id_tournament =Game.id_tournament 

INNER JOIN dbo.Players ON Players.id_player = Game.id_player
WHERE tournemntData.Score = dbo.Game.score
```